# Canada VFS passport multiple package or single

Tags: visas, canada, vfs-global

We applied for a tourist visa for Canada and got the biometrics. We applied as a family and got the email to submit passport.

Application had 2 applicants, so while sending the passport to VAC do we need to buy 2 separate 2way shipping or can we put both applications in single package and buy just one 2way shipping label? Has anyone done Canada visa as group?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But I'll posit that the VAC will want separate shippings, so that each shipment can be tied to an individual application.

Comment: have you sent your passports to VAC? we were also in the same situation (2 applicants in single application). just received email to send passport to VAC today. if you already sent, pls share how to do it